# Regarding verilog always blocks

Tags: verilog, hdl

I have an `always` block that looks like this

```
reg [31:0] r1;

always @(posedge clk)
  if(condition) begin
    r1<=32'hcafecafe;
  end
```

what happens to `r1` when the condition is false? 
What does it get synthesized to ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you have not set any reset condition. 
Your code says if condition is true, r1 should be 32'hcafecafe. If you think about it carefully, if r1 is fixed to 32'hcafecafe, the tool is accomplishing what you have told it to do.

The correct code would be something like this:

```
reg [31:0] r1;

always @(posedge clk)
  if (sync_reset_b == 1) //synchronous reset
      r1<=32'h0; // or whatever you want it to be.
  else if(condition) begin
    r1<=32'hcafecafe;
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried two different synthesisers and both synthesised your code to

```
reg [31:0] r1 = 32'hcafecafe;
```

This is not what I would have expected, because this code does not behave in *exactly* the same way as your RTL. In your RTL, `r1` will be unknown until the first clock edge with `condition` high whereupon it will take the value `32'hcafecafe`. The synthesised output will already have the value `32'hcafecafe` before that first clock edge. I would have expected the synthesiser output to be 32 enabled D-type flip-flops with their inputs tied to  `32'hcafecafe`.

Comment: I presumed the question to be asking if `condition` were tied to a constant 0 and the enable is never true.  In this case `r1` still has to be *something* and the true branch of the conditional seems a good a choice as any.  I suppose 0 would be another fine choice but I think it's up to the compiler at that point.

Comment: This is what is happening currently, but I want the synthesis tool to infer a latch. Is there any way that the synthesis tool will infer a latch and nothing else?

Comment: @a220599 Do you mean  a _latch_? Or a flip-flop?

Comment: I want to infer a latch

Answer (score 0):

I believe a synthesis tool treat this the same as

```
reg [31:0] r1 =32'h????????;

always @(posedge clk)
  if(condition)
    r1<=32'hcafecafe;
  else
   r1 <= r1;
```

Since the initial value is a don't care, the only other possible value is 32'hcafecafe, do the synthesis tool is free to synthesize it to a constant value.

Comment: It should treat it like this, but what it does is synthesize it to r1=32'hcafecafe ( initialize the register to a constant value, instead of a latch or a flop).

Comment: The problem is your example code does not specify what happens when `condition` is false. The flop you want synthesized comes up in a random state. It's possible that random state matches 32'hcafecafe, in which case you would be able to tell the difference between your output being from a flop, or driven by a constant.
You need to specify an initial `r1` state if your technology allows it, or add a reset signal to get your logic synthesized into.a flop.

Comment: The functionality I want is as follows

when the condition is true, r1 is initialized to 32'hcafecafe and it should stay in that state. So you are saying I should define the state for when condition is false?

Comment: You need to define it's initial state as 0 if your tool allows it, or you need to define a reset state.